# Efficient run-time type checking

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, runtime

I have hierarchy of classes like follows (in fact I have more than 3 derived types):

```
class A {};
class B : A  {};
class C : B  {};
class D : A  {};
```

Instances of these classes are stored in `List<A>` collections. Sometimes collections are quite big (thousands or even tens of thousands of objects).

In my code I frequently need to perform some actions depending on the exact type of the objects. Something like this:

```
List<A> collection = ...
foreach (A obj in collection)
{
    if (obj is C)
        something(obj as C);
    else if (obj is B)
        somethingElse(obj as B);
    ....
}
```

As you see, the code performs many checks for type of the object and casts. For collections with many elements performance of the code is not that great.

What would you recommend to speed up run time type checks in my case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should move the "something" into a virtual method on `A`, then each of `B`, `C` and `D` can override it as they need (which may just mean calling an external method - they don't need to do the work themselves) - or *not* override as they need.

Then this becomes:

```
foreach (A obj in collection)
{
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

i.e.

```
class A {
    public virtual void DoSomething() {...}
}
class B : A   {
    public override void DoSomething() {...}
}
```

etc

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go with virtual methods and enums (as @John Leidegren suggested) for some tricky cases.

Answer (score 4):

Make the functionality implemented in the function "something" a behaviour/method of Class A and then redefine it in child classes as applicable (make sure the method is defined as virtual).

In this case you can straight away call:

```
List<A> collection = ...
foreach (A obj in collection)
{
  obj.something()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use only `as` and check for null instead:

```
C c = obj as C;
if (c != null)
    something(c);
```

It will only perform casting once. Both `as` and `is` actually perform casting so there is really no need to use them together.

That being said, casting is relatively cheap. Any performance penalties for casting should be dwarfed by the implementation of `something(c)` or `something(b)`, so don't overthink it unless the amount of types you try to cast to is really significant.

If you are in control of `A`, `B`, `C` classes, see if you can rework your model so you don't need to do casting at all - make use of virtual methods as others suggest.

Comment: I guess that it won't speed up the code. I usually have `if` - `else if` -`else` constructs in my code, so I will need to cast to all types used in checks before performing the checks.

Comment: Use guard clauses. Return right after you casted to anything successfully. It makes your code less "arrow-shaped" and makes it possible for you to only cast right before you need it

Answer (score 2):

There's not a tangible performance difference in using `as` or `is`. What I've seen done in the framework however is that they provide an enum with a unique value for each type. This way you can switch on the type of the object.

Expression trees does this, they have a property called `NodeType` that returns a value containing the type. This way you don't need to do more than one type test.

Then again, Marc just reminded me that these type of situations can sometimes be solved by using polymorphism correctly and that you're having this problem can be a sign of an underlying problem with the way you've written your classes.

Comment: Indeed a `switch(obj.SubType) {...}` can be very effective

Comment: Thanks for enum suggestion. I think it might be handy if used properly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should just use a virtual method. It will result in efficient code that's more readable too.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the clean solution is a virtual method. But sometimes that's not possible. In that case you could use a `Dictionary<Type,Action>`.

```
Dictionary<Type,Action> actions=new Dict...;

Action action;
if(!actions.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out action))
{
  action=GetActionForType(obj.GetType());
  actions.Add(obj.GetType(), action);
}
action();
```

Note that this works only on the exact types, not on derived types. So you might need to add some logic based on `Type.IsAssignableFrom` inside `GetActionForType`.

And obviously this implementation is not threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks, you suggestion about using Dictionary is interesting.

Comment: @Bob Are you sure that you can't use virtual methods?

Comment: @David Heffernan I will definitely use virtual methods for most cases. But maybe in some tricky cases enum will come in handy. Suggestion about Dictionary is interesting in itself (and unique throughout the answers to this question). I mean I don't plan to use it this case, but maybe I'll use it in other code.